# Dataset, virtual or in memory table in Access 2007

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

Is there a way to load data (e.g. from XML) to a dataset - a temporary memory table/recordset which can be linked (bound) to a form for a preview? I know that .NET has datasets, but how about Access 2007?

It is possible to fill a menu/list control with the data from a XML file, but it would not scale as well as a continuous form would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution based on this example: [Create In-Memory ADO Recordsets](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/msaccess/article.php/3846361/Create-In-Memory-ADO-Recordsets.htm)
  - remember to add first a reference in Tools > References, find the latest Microsoft ActiveX Data Object

```
Public Sub createDataSet(mekeNewSet As Boolean)
'requires reference addedd **Microsoft ActiveX Data Object**

Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim fld As ADODB.Field

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
With rs
    .Fields.Append "EmployeeID", adInteger, , adFldKeyColumn
    .Fields.Append "FirstName", adVarChar, 10, adFldMayBeNull
    .Fields.Append "LastName", adVarChar, 20, adFldMayBeNull
    .Fields.Append "Email", adVarChar, 64, adFldMayBeNull
    .Fields.Append "Include", adInteger, , adFldMayBeNull
    .Fields.Append "Selected", adBoolean, , adFldMayBeNull
    .CursorType = adOpenKeyset
    .CursorLocation = adUseClient
    .LockType = adLockPessimistic
    .Open
End With

With rs
    .AddNew
    .Fields(0) = 777
    .Fields(1) = "John"
    .Fields(2) = "Smith"
    .Fields(3) = "john.smith@something.com"
    .Fields(4) = 1
    .Fields(5) = True
    .Update
End With


Set Me.Recordset = rs

End Sub
```

There is also a possibility to create a new Class in VBA and then build a Collection as in this tutorial: [Using Custom Collections in Microsoft Access](http://www.databaseadvisors.com/newsletters/newsletter200503/0503usingcustomcollections/using%20custom%20collections%20in%20microsoft%20access.asp)

For the full solution how to download XML data and enter it into a recordser check here:
[Access VBA - how to download XML file and enter its data into a recordset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7091162/access-vba-how-to-download-xml-file-and-enter-its-data-into-a-recordset/7120376#7120376)

Comment: How does this address the "can be linked (bound) to a form for a preview" part of the question?

Comment: Easy, with Set Me.Recordset = rs. "Me" is the form where this code is executed. The fields in the form should be bound to the same names (data source) as this recordest has e.g. "EmployeeID", "FirstName" and so on.

Comment: I think you should say something explicit about that, and explain why you have it commented out in your code.

Answer (score 1):

No, Access doesn't know datasets.
But you could convert the dataset to an `ADODB.Recordset`. Access knows that and you can bind it directly to a continuous form.

Here is a snippet to convert datasets to ADODB.Recordsets (and the other way round):
http://dotnet-snippets.de/dns/ado-recordset-converter-SID525.aspx

The page and the comments in the code are in German, but even if you don't understand German, the code itself is easy to use.
You just need a reference to `Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8`, and then you just need to call this method:

```
public static ADODB.Recordset ConvertDataTableToRecordset(DataTable table)
```

Comment: That is written in C# .NET, so it is not straight forward to convert it but it does give some ideas, like creating a recordset from scratch, which may be what I need, I'll have to try.

Comment: Sorry, I think I misread your question. I thought you already have a .NET DataSet and just want to display it in Access. I'll leave my answer as it is, maybe it helps you anyway...

Answer (score 1):

Access forms starting with A2000 allow the assignment of a recordset assembled in code to a form's recordset, and that includes ADO recordsets. So, if you opened an ADO recordset from your XML file, you should then be able to assign it to a form.

However, note that this is not something I have ever done as I haven't needed it, and I know that there are issues with ADO vs. DAO recordsets and all sorts of little incompatibilities that people encounter when they do this kind of thing.