# Using VBA To Import XML website into Access

Tags: xml, ms-access, vba

I wish to download the exchange rates from this website on a weekly basis using VBA
I am very new to XML and have been looking around on stack exchange and have seen a few implementations that use a form (i want to avoid this method)

I have tried to import it using MS Access Wizard but all the fields in the tables are blank

I would like to implement these steps if possible

1. Download the XML from the web page http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml
2. Loop through the XML and place the currency and the exchange rate into either a new or existing two column table

Currently i have the below code. But its obviously put together based on other peoples work and is more a template to work off of than anything else
Can anyone point me in the right direction

```
Sub Test()

'**********************************************************
' DOWNLOAD XML DATA
' ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7091162/access-vba-how-to-download-xml-file- and-enter-its-data-into-a-recordset
'**********************************************************

Dim obj As MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP
Set obj = New MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP

obj.Open "GET", "http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml", False
'in case you are sending a form *POST* or XML data to a SOAP server set content type
obj.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
obj.send

Dim status As Integer
status = obj.status

If status >= 400 And status <= 599 Then
    Debug.Print "Error Occurred : " & obj.status & " - " & obj.statusText
End If

   '**********************************************************
   'CREATE XML DOM DOCUMENT
   '**********************************************************

Dim xmlDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument
Dim xmlElement As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement
Dim xmlNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement
Set xmlDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument
xmlDoc.loadXML (obj.responseText)

   '**********************************************************
   'ACCESS ROWS
   'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305/how-to-parse-xml-in-vba
   '**********************************************************

Dim point As IXMLDOMNode
Set point = xmlDoc.firstChild

Debug.Print point.selectSingleNode("subject").Text

End Sub
```

Comment: You can simplify the start of this task by loading the `DOMDocument` directly from the url instead of first fetching the XML and then loading that XML into the document.  Do this: `xmlDoc.async = False` And then this: `xmlDoc.Load "http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml"`

Comment: Thanks HansUp, This is indeed far better. DO you have any idea how to extract the elements from the XMLDOC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use XPath to select the elements you want and then `getAttribute` to extract the values for the `currency` and `rate` attributes from each selected element.

```vb
Const cstrXPath As String = "/gesmes:Envelope/Cube/Cube/Cube"
Dim xmlDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument
Dim xmlElement As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement
Dim xmlSelection As MSXML2.IXMLDOMSelection
Dim i As Long
Dim strUrl As String

strUrl = "http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/" & _
    "eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml"

Set xmlDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument
xmlDoc.async = False
xmlDoc.Load strUrl

Set xmlSelection = xmlDoc.SelectNodes(cstrXPath)
Debug.Print "xmlSelection.Length: " & xmlSelection.Length
i = 1
For Each xmlElement In xmlSelection
    Debug.Print i, xmlElement.getAttribute("currency"), _
        xmlElement.getAttribute("rate")
    i = i + 1
Next xmlElement
```

You can view the output in the Immediate window; you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> to go there.  Here is an abbreviated output sample ...

```vb
xmlSelection.Length: 32
 1            USD           1.3495
 2            JPY           136.93
 3            BGN           1.9558
```

Ultimately you want to store those values, not just `Debug.Print` them.  When you get to that point, notice `getAttribute` returns text values.  If you will be storing `rate` in a numeric field, eg. Single, you can transform the text value to a number when you store it.

```vb
CSng(xmlElement.getAttribute("rate"))
```

Comment: Thank you very much Hansup, This is exactly what i was looking for. Have a nice weekend

Comment: This is great, and works nicely for that website; I'd like to apply the same principles to this website: https://www.sec.gov/rss/investor/alerts but it doesn't have the gesmes (I have googled that but really don't understand it yet). How to apply to this website? I'd like to extract Item, description, pubdate and link from that site. Many thanks.

Comment: "gesmes" is not a standard feature of XML documents, so I think you would be better off to google XPath instead.