# What is the best way to routinely import a CSV or XML file into a MS access database?

Tags: csv, ms-access, automation, vba, ms-access-2013

I have an Access database that keeps track of many different aspects of my companies performance and I would like to add functionality to keep track of the hours the employees are working.

The hours are all kept track of on a website called timetracker. They have a few reporting options including XML and CSV files. The site has a favorite report feature to get the same data in the format that I want it every week.

What I would like to do is find the best process for getting the data from this website, into a table in my database that I can reference.

*I will not be the one executing whatever process I come up with and I would really like it to be as easy as possible for whoever it is that does have to do it.*

Right now I have a linked table that is an XML file in our SharePoint folder. I was thinking that maybe we could just run the report and download the file every week then just save it over the old file with the correct sheet names and it should update.

What I am wondering is if anyone can come up with an easier process for doing this that would take the least amount of time and be easiest to write down instructions for that anyone could execute. 
(Would it maybe be possible to create some sort of macro to actually download the report automatically?)

Comment: Well, natively Access comes with an "Important from an XML File" button. Does that not work for the XML portion?

Comment: It does work pretty well but the user will still have to download and import the file each week. I realize these aren't difficult tasks, but given that my boss will be doing them every single week once my database is finished,  I'm just trying to see if anyone has any ideas that could cut out any steps.

Comment: Have you read this already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7091162/access-vba-how-to-download-xml-file-%20and-enter-its-data-into-a-recordset

Comment: I read it to see if it could be useful but it seems a little more involved than what is necessary for this problem. I am just trying to replace a file in my database with one that I download online with as little steps for the user as possible. Correct me if I'm wrong, but from my understanding I shouldn't need to implement the solutions in the answers of that question.